# Split gateway and mask in angular input

Tags: angularjs, view, ip, gateway

I have an input field of IP Gateway and Mask in this form `__.__.__.__/__` . 
I want to split mask input which is after `/` in another model to bind So that it will be like this:

```
{
"Gateway" : "10.20.30.40",
"Mask": "23"
}
```

How can I cut value after `/__` for mask. 
**IP address setup:**

```
$("#IP").inputmask({ /
    mask: "i[i[i]].i[i[i]].i[i[i]].i[i[i]]/99",
    definitions: {
        'i': {
            validator: function (chrs, buffer, pos, strict, opts) {
                if (pos - 1 > -1 && buffer[pos - 1] != ".") {
                chrs = buffer[pos - 1] + chrs;
                    if (pos - 2 > -1 && buffer[pos - 2] != ".") {
                    chrs = buffer[pos - 2] + chrs;
                        } else chrs = "0" + chrs;
                        } else chrs = "00" + chrs;
                        return new RegExp("25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01][0-9][0-9]").test(chrs);
                        },
                        cardinality: 1
                    }
        }
});
```

**EDIT :-
added view and controller**

```
<div class="input-group sepH_b">    
            <span class="input-group-addon" id="reg_input">Gateway</span>
          <input class="form-control" id="IP" type="text" ng-model="inf.Gateway" required>
</div>
```

**In Ctrl**

```
$scope.master = {};
$scope.addData = function() { 
$scope.master = angular.copy($scope.inf);
};
```

`master{}` is where data is getting binded.

Comment: I cant see any angularJS code here.  Share the demo code where we can see your `<form>` and `js` file

Comment: @ShashankVivek I have added the view and ctrl in my EDIT

Answer (score 0):

1. Do not use jquery with angularJS
2. Why not create a different model which will be more readable to others. [Check this plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/9Q8QAWKcwieLd4NbFDzI?p=preview). Add necessary validations accordingly. Yoou dont need to write extra code to extract `mask` and anyone can access `port1`,`port2` etc properties as per their requirement.

Something like below:

```
  $scope.gateway = {
    port1 : 0,
    port2:  0,
    port3 : 0,
    port4: 0
  };
  $scope.mask = 0
```

Comment: I don't prefer jquery over angular script like u said. I had solved it using regex code which will search for `/` and divide the models. Besides my JSON raw body structure is in this way `{ "gateway": "" , "mask":""}`